# Couchbase .NET SDK Connection Issue “Unable to locate node” on openstack

Tags: c#, .net, couchbase, openstack

I installed the Couchebase under openstack. When I add record to couchebase, there is an error.
"Enable to connect node"
This hapen only when we install couchebase under openstack, otherwise bellow code work fine.

```
var configuration = new Couchbase.Configuration.CouchbaseClientConfiguration();
configuration.Bucket = "BucketName";
configuration.Urls.Add(new Uri(couchUrl));
Couchbase.CouchbaseClient couchClient = couchClient = new Couchbase.CouchbaseClient(configuration);
 TestConnectivity testObj = new TestConnectivity();

var result = couchClient.ExecuteStore(Enyim.Caching.Memcached.StoreMode.Set, "TestObject123", 
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testObj));`
```